PHPickerViewController: present images in reverse order
I am using PHPickerViewController to get assets from the photo library. It works fine, but it presents images so that the newest is first. I would like to choose the order. In some cases I prefer the oldest image to be first.
I have checked in PHPickerConfiguration with no success. I'm just wondering if it is possible.

No. You'd have to write your own picker interface.
